# How to encrypt my code with proGuard tool

Tags: java, proguard

I did but it fail. Fail info:`can't to link the web,the error code is 404.` My project is a web project with Spring MVC.
I have set up to ignore files: controller, pojo and service.
Thank you.

Comment: How you are obfuscating your project?

Comment: Just want to know...why you are obfuscating your web project as the code is never going to available to client?

Comment: I just want to test.